How to lock certain excel cells with excel interop from vSTO
I am developing a VSTO add-in. This add-in generates one new sheet _worksheet, which has certain cells that the user should not be able to change.
For example, cell AV27 holds some information that must stay there.
I tried locking with
private void LockCells()
{
    _worksheet.Range["AV27"].Locked = true;
    _worksheet.Protect("somepassword");
}

But that protects the entire sheet. I can no longer change the value of B3 for example. Removing the line
_worksheet.Protect("somepassword");

leaves all cells unlocked.
Is there anything I can do?

I figured it out.

By default all cells in an excel worksheet have a Locked property applied, but it has no effect unless sheet protection is used. What you first need to do is select the cells which you want to remain editable then go to Format> Cells - Protection to clear the Locked checkbox.

Meaning one has to firt unlock the cells where the editing is allowed and then protect the sheet.
